# Gravity sensor in Android manifest <uses-feature>

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

This may be a simple question, but I tried to use

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gravity"
              android:required="true" />
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml file and it seemed to compile, but when I went to Google Play and uploaded my APK, it doesn't seem to recognize it and says "0 supported devices." The documentation doesn't mention android.hardware.sensor.gravity in uses-feature, but you can still use it I guess as it compiles? Is the gravity sensor a part of something else that I don't about? I removed the gravity sensor uses-feature and the Google Play error disappears, so this is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The documentation doesn't mention android.hardware.sensor.gravity in uses-feature, but you can still use it I guess as it compiles?

You can put any string in there you want. Only the documented ones will have a useful effect.

> Is the gravity sensor a part of something else that I don't about?

Not from the standpoint of `<uses-feature>`. There is no hardware "gravity" sensor. What you think of as `TYPE_GRAVITY` is a virtual sensor, as is `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION`. Those values are generated based on other sensors, such as the accelerometer.

Answer (score 1):

Gravity sensor is a virtual or in some devices - hardware sensor. In case if g-sensor is virtual it depends on two hardware sensors: gyroscope and accelerometer. [See table 1](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-intro) and a table [here](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types.html#composite_sensor_type_summary)
However exclusion of this two sensors by `<uses-feature>` will shorten your supported devices list in Play Market. In my case it was from over 9000 to ~2000 devices.